# Validating fields using Yii

Tags: php, mysql, validation, yii

I have two related models i.e. Candidate and Qualifications. They have one to many relationship between them. I am using CActiveForm and using transaction to insert the related data. As you can see from the code below that PK of candidate is auto generated and is being send to qualification model as FK.
**Controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Candidate;
    $q=new Qualification;
    if(isset($_POST['Candidate'], $_POST['Qualification'])){
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Candidate'];
        $q->attributes=$_POST['Qualification'];

                if ($model->validate()) {
                $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
                $success = $model->save(false);
                $q->candidate_id = $model->id;
                $success = $success ? $q->save() : $success;

                if ($success){
                    $transaction->commit();
                }
                else{
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }


    }
```

I am able to insert the data but i am unable to handle validation of qualification. By using the above code if i leave a required field of qualification model, it generates an error ( which i don't want). I want qualification validation should trigger before submit. It should highlight error as it does for candidate.
**_form**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'father_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'father_name',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'father_name'); ?>
</div>
........

 <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($qualification,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($qualification,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($qualification,'name'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach of what you already have:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $candidate=new Candidate();
    $qualification=new Qualification();

    if (isset($_POST['Candidate'], $_POST['Qualification'])) {
        $candidate->attributes=$_POST['Candidate'];
        $qualification->attributes=$_POST['Qualification'];

        $error = false;
        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (!$candidate->save()) {
                throw new CException(CHtml::errorSummary($candidate));
            }
            $qualification->candidate_id = $candidate->id;
            if (!$qualification->save()) {
                throw new CException(CHtml::errorSummary($qualification));
            }
            $transaction->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }

        if (!$error) {
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$candidate->id));
        }

        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is indeed working, but this is not overriding errorSummary() of CActiveForm i.e. it is displaying errors separately not with form error which are being displayed by <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

Comment: calling CHtml::errorSummary doesnt makes any impact over the fact that later in your form you call $form->error($model, 'attribute'); Just remove the `echo $error` from my example and display the errors with `$form->error()` as you already do.